# Is there a way to show that an arbitrary function is continuous?

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

First, I know that there are methods for showing (once some primitive functions have been so proven) that various combinations  of continuous functions are also continuous (I do not address such functions). Also, I am aware that if a function is differentiable then it is automatically continuous. I allow all that.

My question actually arose by considering that the usual definition of continuity is not *directly* applicable, as it gives a criterion for continuity only point-by-point, whereas most functions are defined over uncountably infinitely many points. (This is especially perplexing in the multivariable case when, to be continuous at a point the function must possess a unique limit *however it is approached,* which is inifinite, as opposed to just the two possibilities in the single variable case). But *let us stick to the single variable case* without loss of generality.

> So suppose we have a function defined on some interval $I$. Furthermore, do *not* let it be differentiable in $I$, neither let it be some combination of known functions. Then *how* can we know whether this function is continuous in $I$?

Thank you.

Comment: "Indeed, if a function can be integrated over some domain, it must be at least piecewise continuous over that domain." If by piecewise continuous you mean, for example, when the domain is an interval, that there exists a partition it such that the function is continuous restricted to each subinterval, the proposition is false. Thomae's function can be Riemann-integrated but it's continuous only at the irrational numbers.

The result is that if a function can be integrated then the set on which it's discontinuous has zero measure. But that set can still be infinite, uncountable, or dense.

Comment: @Nell Well, what if these subintervals can have length zero too?

Comment: An interval has length zero iff it consists in just a point. So if the starting interval is not a point then you can't define a partition of it consisting on zero-measure intervals, since by definition, a partition of an interval must be finite and the interval is an infinite set.

Comment: Your question can't really be answered unless you say what you mean by "we have a function defined on some interval $I$". If you don't know anything about the function, then one of its properties that you don't know is continuity.

Comment: @Nell I don't mean the interval over which the function is integrable. I mean some of the subintervals over which it is continuous.

Comment: Thomae's function is a function which is Riemann-integrable, but there is no nontrivial interval over which it's continuous.

Comment: @Nell Not even at irrational points, which are just vanishing intervals?

Comment: If you mean the intervals $[s,s]$ where $s$ is irrational, that's a trivial interval. That's why I said that there is no nontrivial interval on which it's continuous.

And you can't make a piecewise continuous function from its value on trivial intervals.

Comment: @Nell I don't think I agree, but I'll let it rest at that.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying at least some characteristic of the function must be known? If so I have given some of its negative characteristics (it's nowhere differentiable on $I$ and is not a combination of elementary functions).

Comment: It's not a matter of you agreeing to it or not. It's a function which is Riemann-Integrable, but it's not piecewise continuous, that's a fact.

Comment: To see why your approach doesn't work let's take a particular case of it. Let's say $I=[0,1]$ and $f$ is the Thomae's function on it. If $f$ were piecewise continuous there would be some points (A partition) of $[0,1]$ given by $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n=1$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. Note that each of these intervals has an infinite number of points. But if you take a rational number $r_i$ in each of them, then $f$ is discontinuous at $r_i$, a contradiction. Thus, $f$ is not piecewise continuous. And by Lebesgue Criterion $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Those negative characteristics are insufficient to determine continuity. You use words like "impractical": for a practical method, you need to say something about how the function is given to you. I am afraid it is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Nell Well, I see your point now. Going to edit OP. Thank you.

Comment: @RobArthan Well, I don't know how you concluded that those conditions are insufficient. To be clearer, when I said (or meant) the usual definitions were not **directly** applicable, I was referring to the fact that they are defined only for one point when a function usually is defined at uncountably infinitely many points. I was asking if there were other methods that didn't use this point by point approach. I'm going to edit the OP to clarify this. Thank you.

Comment: "Nowhere differentiable" is a statement about all points.  "Not a combination of elementary functions" doesn't really mean anything unless you define what "combinations" are allowed, but it sounds like a statement about all points. I look forward to your clarifications.

Comment: Yes, if we denote this real-valued function of one real variable by $f$, and consider it only in some interval $I$, then I'm saying: (1) Imagine that $f$ it is not differentiable in $I$, and that (2) $f$ cannot be expressed as the usual combinations of functions -- addition, multiplication, composition, etc. I am saying this simply to emphasize that I am aware of the usual ways of showing continuity. If it will help, you can think of the OP as asking how *any* function can be tested for continuity over its domain *directly.* Is this clearer now?

Comment: @RobArthan  I think I might be seeing that what I'm asking about may stem from a certain misunderstanding of the definition of continuity -- or rather of its application. The definition in itself usually doesn't suffice. Seems we must also know the function specifically at all points where it is defined to be able to tell. In other words, one must really understand the function, and the pointwise definition *always* suffices. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "general way". The argument will always depend on the particular function you are studying. If the tools you know about don't help you then you have to go back to the definition of continuity.

Sorry.

Comment: I didn't mean "general way" as in absolutely applicable algorithm. Sorry if I was unclear (I've edited the question). My question is closer to what your penultimate sentence suggests: How is it possible to apply the definition over an interval (as opposed to just, say, at most countably infinitely many points)? This is what I want to know. Thank you.

Comment: In other words: What are these other tools apart from the ones mentioned in the OP?

Comment: If you are lucky the tools you know tell you about continuity at most points. Then you have to study only a few with particular care. For example, think about $x\sin (1/x)$ on $[-1, 1]$, defined as $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I ruled out such cases in the OP. Let the function not be differentiable at any point. Is there no way you know about?

Comment: There may be tools/theorems other than the ones you know. My original answer still says you have to deal with each particular function starting from its definition. If you have one you are concerned about, as a new question just about that function.

Comment: Of course there may be. That's exactly what I'm asking about. What are they?

Comment: If such exist others will have to provide them here. No need for us to discuss further.

Comment: I think I might be seeing that what I'm asking about may stem from a certain misunderstanding of the definition of continuity -- or rather of its application. The definition in itself usually doesn't suffice. Seems one must also know the function specifically at all points where it is defined to be able to tell. In other words, one must really understand the function, and the pointwise definition *always* suffices. I think I should accept your answer as it is closest to this realisation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An usually good tool to prove a function is continuous (In any metric space) is that $f$ is continuous if for any convergent sequence $x_n\to x$, you get $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

However there is no good way which works in general. Sometimes the function, its domain, or range are just too strange and you can't easily prove it's continuous.

Comment: But that is just a rephrasing of the $\epsilon \delta$ definition. It still shows continuity at one point alone. How can one apply this over a set with uncountably infinitely many points? Is there a better way? This is the meat of my question.

Comment: @Allawonder: It's not just a rephrasing -- they happen to be equivalent for $\mathbb R$, but there are topological spaces for which sequential continuity doesn't imply continuity. For example if $X$ is the [long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) extended with a point at infinity, then every function $X\to\mathbb R$ is sequentially continuous at $\infty$, but not all are continuous.

Comment: Obviously. But weren't we talking about just metric spaces (in particular subsets of $\mathbb R^i$)?

Comment: Of course. But I have since the OP been concentrating in particular on functions on some interval of $\mathbb R$, so that the sequential definition is equivalent in this case. This is what I meant.

Comment: Another thing I meant is, even suppose we talk about more general spaces, then this definition is analogous to the $\epsilon\,\delta$ one in the sense that it can only be used to show continuity point by point. The OP is asking whether there are other ways that don't go point by point. Am I sufficiently clear now?

Comment: Well, it's equivalent in this case. But I don't know what would you expect. If you have a condition $C$ under which you can determine whether a function is continuous or not, then that condition is equivalent to continuity.

Comment: A non-point-based condition is that $f$ is continuous if for each open set in the range, the preimage is also an open set. But in the case of metric spaces the easiest open set is a ball, and you'll get something like

"For any open ball $B$ in the range, $p^{-1}(B)$ is an union of open balls $B'$ such that $p(B')\subseteq B$." This condition is exactly a rephrasing of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, once you give a center and radius to each ball.

Comment: So you may end up with a seemingly global condition for continuity, but continuity is really a local condition, so you'll have to check on each point, or on each open set, and usually there are more open sets than points.

Comment: Thank you, Nell. I think I might be seeing that what I'm asking about may stem from a certain misunderstanding of the definition of continuity -- or rather of its application. The definition in itself usually doesn't suffice. Seems one must also know the function specifically at all points where it is defined to be able to tell. In other words, one must really understand the function, and the pointwise definition *always* suffices.

Comment: And BTW, one uses the article "an" only before vowel sounds in English. I noticed you used "an" before such words as "usually", whose first syllable is a consonant sound /j/ as in the first syllable of "yield".

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove that a function $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous is to apply the [uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem). In order to satisfy the hypothesis of that theorem, you are required to prove that $f$ is a uniform limit of some sequence $f_i : I \to \mathbb{R}$ of continuous functions.

This is indeed how one usually constructs examples of [nowhere differentiable, continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), namely by constructing, by very careful and clever methods, a very particular sequence of continuous functions $f_i$ which is a Cauchy sequence in the [uniform metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) on the set of continuous functions $C(I,\mathbb{R})$. That sequence has a continuous limit (by the uniform limit theorem). If the sequence was constructed cleverly enough, one can prove that the limit is nowhere differentiable.